# How to store a function ( or lambda ) inside a map and then execute it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to have a MutableMap which maps classes on some logic. It is mainly use to react on some objects which arrives from backend. E.g.

```
class ViewUpdater(val view: RecordingActivity) {
    val map: MutableMap<KClassifier, Function<*>> = mutableMapOf()

    init {
        map[Entity1::class] = { m: Entity ->
            view.entity1.text = (m as Entity1).value1.toString()
        }
        map[Entity2::class] = { m: Entity ->
            view.entity2.text = (m as Entity2).value2.toString()
        }
}
```

But I don't know if the type `Function<*>` is even the right one. After that, obviously I would like to execute my functions/lambdas when having a specific object in hand: e.g.

```
 .subscribe(
            { it: Entity ->
                   map[it::class] // and what next here... ?
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
MutableMap < KClass<Entity>, (Entity) -> Unit >  = mutableMapOf()
```

or:

```
MutableMap < KClass<Entity>, Function1<Entity, Unit> >  = mutableMapOf()
```

**instead of using map you can use this method**:

```
fun <T: Entity> setViewText(en: T) =
             when(en){
               is Entity1 -> view.entity1.text = en.value1.toString()
               is Entity2 -> view.entity2.text = en.value2.toString()
               else -> throw Exception("Invalid Entity")
             }
```

you dont get subscribe signature but i *guess* you may run it like this (if subscribe gets a lambda argument as `(Entity) -> Unit` and has an Entity receiver ):

```
.subscribe{ map[this::class] } // if subscribe has Entity receiver
```

if subscribe has not Entity receiver:

```
.subscribe{ map[it::class]?.invoke(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `invoke()` operator. In your case, you can simply do:

```
.subscribe { map[it::class]?.invoke(it) }
```

Note that this may return null if you didn't have a function mapped for the specific `Entity` subclass. Alternatively, I might suggest using a `when` statement as an extension function for readability, if your intent is to map specific subclasses of `Entity` to a `String`. For example:

```
fun Entity.toSpecialString() : String = when(this) {
    is Entity1 -> value1.toString()
    is Entity2 -> value2.toString()
    else -> "unspecified"
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
.subscribe { it.toSpecialString() }
```